# Wait for Promise before calling another promise from inside a for loop - Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

**Problem:** I need to call an API one after the other from inside the `for` loop. I need to wait for former API to resolve before calling the latter one.

I am calling a Get API inside a for loop which generate Document on server side , as shown below

```
 async ExtendedMethod() {
    let MList: PendingListMemberWise[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.MemberList.length; i++) {
      if (this.MemberList[i].checked) {
        MList.push(this.MemberList[i]);
      }
    }
    this.ShowLoader = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < MList.length; i++) {
      this.lblText = "Generating PDF " + i + "/" + MList.length;
    await this.callGeneratePDFAPI(MList[i]);
    }
    this.lblText = "PDF Generation Completed";
    this.GetBranchList();
    this.ShowLoader = false;
    //this.appconfig.Message="PDF Files have been Generated , Use the Download PDF Link to Download Them";
  }
```

And

```
 callGeneratePDFAPI(mcodeList: PendingListMemberWise) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var url = this.baseurl + 'api/GeneratePDF/GeneratePDF/' + mcodeList.memberCode + '/' + sessionStorage.getItem("UserID");
      this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(result => {
          var index = this.MemberList.indexOf(mcodeList);
          if (index > -1) {
            this.MemberList.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }, error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      resolve();
    })
  }
```

when I call callGeneratePDFAPI() inside foor loop and send parameter one by one than it hit the API in Async , Means it does not wait for first call to finish before making another http call ,

Idea to solve this was to use promise as

```
    TestMethod() {
    try {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Some Code here
        resolve();
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

And then

```
 this.TestMethod()).then(() => {
      //Another task to do after TestMethod return 
    });
```

But how can I use it inside for loop , I have to make request 10 times so I can show user that out of 10 , n number of document has been created .

How to use sync api call instead of by default async call in angular

**Update 1**

```
ExtendedMethod() {
let MList: PendingListMemberWise[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.MemberList.length; i++) {
  if (this.MemberList[i].checked) {
    MList.push(this.MemberList[i]);
  }
}
this.ShowLoader = true;
var promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < MList.length; i++) {
  this.lblText = "Generating PDF " + i + "/" + MList.length;
  promises.push(this.callGeneratePDFAPI(MList[i]));
}
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((response) => {console.log('All Done') });
this.lblText = "PDF Generation Completed";
this.GetBranchList();
this.ShowLoader = false;
//this.appconfig.Message="PDF Files have been Generated , Use the Download PDF Link to Download Them";
```

}

Comment: Should resolve() not be inside the subcribe(result =>{ }) block? Or just use toPromise() method that tano mentions.

Comment: @louisvno, yes I used .toPromise() and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async/await.

```
**async** ExtendedMethod() {
    let MList: PendingListMemberWise[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.MemberList.length; i++) {
      if (this.MemberList[i].checked) {
        MList.push(this.MemberList[i]);
      }
    }
    this.ShowLoader = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < MList.length; i++) {
      this.lblText = "Generating PDF " + i + "/" + MList.length;
      **await** this.callGeneratePDFAPI(MList[i]);
    }
    this.lblText = "PDF Generation Completed";
    this.GetBranchList();
    this.ShowLoader = false;
    //this.appconfig.Message="PDF Files have been Generated , Use the Download PDF Link to Download Them";
  }

  callGeneratePDFAPI(mcodeList: PendingListMemberWise) {
    var url = this.baseurl + 'api/GeneratePDF/GeneratePDF/' + mcodeList.memberCode + '/' + sessionStorage.getItem("UserID");
    const service = this.http.get(url).toPromise();
    service.then(result => {
        var index = this.MemberList.indexOf(mcodeList);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.MemberList.splice(index, 1);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
      return service;
  }
```

Comment: again its async call , will it wait for first call to finish before making next call ??

Comment: await is waiting for async call to be ended. You have to return with toPromise() instead of observable. e.g.: this.http.get(...).toPromise()

Comment: Any Post you can refer ?

Comment: Please check updated Question with async await , but still it create multiple http calls at same time

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1:-**

To make requests synchronously, try the below idea.

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce((acc, element, index) => {
  return acc.then(() => {
    console.log('Generating PDF: ', index + 1);
    return callGeneratePDFAPI();
  })
}, Promise.resolve());

function callGeneratePDFAPI(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  })
};
```

---

You can use `Promise.all` method.

Run your for loop and collect promises in an array `promises`. Then call the below code:-

```
var promises = [];

<your_array>.forEach(element => {
  // push into promises
})
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((response) => {});
```

For a live example, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

---

Please note `then` will fire once all the promises resolve and you will get all the data in an array. If any of the promise rejects, then you need to catch it.

Comment: Please read the code again not just title , there is nothing to do inside then() , everything is happening inside api call , still your snippet send multiple request without waiting for previous calls to finish

Comment: @Jack, you want all the requests to be fired at once or after one after the other. Also, it would be great if you could create a stckblitz for better code readability.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but its clearly mentioned in question = "wait for first call to finish before making another http call" , Which is one after the other

Comment: please check Update 1 , I have tried as you suggested but still it make multiple calls at same time

Comment: @Jack - It will make multiple requests only. You can use async / await as suggested in another example. If you want a sample, please create a stackblitz for us to help you better.

Comment: I have updated my question with async await too , sorry for stackblitz  because cant consume api in there

Comment: I tried this but it does not work , its same as my update 1 , already tried

Comment: @Jack - Please check update 1 now. You can use this idea to implement what you are looking for.

Comment: no it does not even in the scene . Maybe its because of unavailability of Actual API for you , but I tried tano's idea . Use of .toPromise() send API request in non Asynchronized way, problem solved